# Initialize state before mapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, antd

I know my question comes from a misunderstanding of react-redux but I will describe my use case hoping someone will point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to store selected row keys (selectedRowKeys) from a table (ant design table) inside of a redux store. Everything works when the store structure is simple like this:

```js
selectedRowKeys: []
```

But I want to store that state in a normalized form to handle multiple tables and multiple table properities:

```js
tables: {
 123fdfas-234dasf-234asdf-23rfa : { //table id
    id: 123fdfas-234dasf-234asdf-23rfa,
    selectedRowKesy: []
    //... other properities
    }
}
```

The problem is that this state doesn't exist when redux is trying to mapStateToProps like this:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  if (!ownProps.id) {
    ownProps.id = uuidv4();
  }

  return {
    selectedRowKeys: state.tables[ownProps.id].selectRowKeys
  };
};
```

`state.tables[ownProps.id]` is undefined so there is an error.

I thought that I need to initialize the state somehow but this led me to even more confusion. What I  have figured out so far:

- I can't initialize state in reducer like `reducerName (state = initialState, action)` because action is not dispatched and there is no `action.id` (action object has a payload with table id).
- I can't dispatch an action `INIT_TABLE` in `componentDidMount()` because mapStateToProps executes first so `state.tables[ownProps.id]` is still undefined.

I feel like this use case is wierd and that is way I cannot find the solution although I have been googling and thinking about this for 3 days.

Please guide me, I'm in a crazy loop :)

This is my first SO question, pls let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: Can you map `state: state.tables[ownProps.id]` instead? This will initially be undefined, and you can use some conditional logic, and only use `state.selectedRowKeys` in the component once `state` is not undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who is responsible for creating a new table? That's the deciding factor on how to solve this problem.

The id definitely shouldnt be created in `mapStateToProps` and you shouldn't mutate `ownProps`. I'm surprised if that even works. Id should be created in action if using redux.

If your React-app has some mechanism which creates a new table (for example, user clicks button), then that's where you should dispatch initialization action. If you really can't find parent component which would be responsible for table initialization, then maybe it is responsibility of this component and you should dispatch the action in `componentDidMount`.

Regardless of which option you pick, your `mapStateToProps` should handle empty state gracefully ie. `selectedRowKeys` should be set to some default value if it's missing (empty array or null maybe?). And your component should handle missing values if there is no sane default available. It's common to have some null checks in render-function which return `null` until data is available.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about dispatching an action in a parent component.
Also, you are right about mutating ownPops - that's stupid. 

Do you agree with Sultan that mapStateToProps should return 'tables'?
My component structure is:
App > CaseList > Table (ant design UI kit) 
I cannot modify Table component and dispatching an action in componentDidMount won't work (explained in my question)  so I guess I need another wrapper.

Comment: I'd probably pass only one table, unless you need all. Ie. mapStateToProps would return `{ table: state.tables[ownProps.id] }`. Table will be undefined if initialization action isn't done yet so you have to handle that situation in the component. Ie. in render method/function at top, you have something like `if (!this.props.table) return null;`. Then you can safely dispatch initialization in `componentDidMount` or somewhere else.

Comment: Got it. This was the missing part: `if (!this.props.table) return null;`
I don't mutate ownProps nad poprs any more and I've understood that props should be used only to pass something from parent component. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding to the problem, you are being too specific!

In this case, it's not a good practice.
I advice the follow.

Supposing that you have the reducer `tables`:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ tables }, ownProps) => {
  return {
    tables,
  };
};
```

This will maket the reducers `tables` available at your component's `this.props`

Thus, you can do the follow wherever you want in the component to get your selected rows, define this method and use it in a proper place instead of directly doing it in mapStateToProps, which is not a good practice.

```
getSelectedRowKeys = (ownProps) => {
  if (!ownProps.id) {
    ownProps.id = uuidv4();
  }
  const selectedRowKeys = [];
  const table = this.props.tables[ownProps.id];
  const selectedRowKeys = table && table.selectRowKeys; //if table exists get the row keys.

  return selectedRowKeys || []; //if selectedRowKeys are not there return an empty array.
}
```